# How to get the container id in javascript or in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have some HTML blocks look like

```
<li id="item261">
    <div class="itemdesc">
      <a class="icon-hide">Hide</a>
    </div>
</li>
```

And i have a jquery like

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
$('.icon-hide').click(function(){
          var elemId = $(this).parent().attr("id");         
    });
});
```

I need the ID of the "li" tag on click of ".icon-hide". how can i achive this? any help..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'd suggest:

```
$('.icon-hide').click(function(){
    var elemId = $(this).closest('li').attr('id');
});
```

This is because `parent()` as implied in the name of the method looks at the *parent* of the element returned by the selector (the parent is the `div`); whereas `closest()` continues up the ancestor tree to match the first selector passed to the method.

You could, instead, use `parents()`, however the important difference between `closest()` and `parents()` is that `closest()` returns *zero or one* match, whereas `parents()` will continue all the way to the root element and return *every* match it finds, so it can return *zero, one or many* matches.

Another difference is that `parents()` starts searching from the current element's parent, whereas `closest()` starts with the current element itself, so it's quite easily possible, using `closest()` for the method to return the current/`$(this)` element itself.

References:

- [`closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/).
- [`parent()`](http://api.jquery.com/parent/).
- [`parents()`](http://api.jquery.com/parents/).

Answer (score 0):

```
$(this).closest('li[id]').attr('id')
```